# what is the use of Lucene Analyzer when i use StringField and StoredField

Tags: java, lucene

if i use only StringField and StoredField for indexing and searching, what is the use of Analyzers?

Since StringFields are not tokenized, i would like to know what is the real usage of analyzers here?

Can i write lucene indexing without Analyzers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `StoredField`, no indexing is happening at all. The document is just stored.

If you use `StringField`, the entire field is indexed as a single token, and there is no point in using analyzers. I just tried to run the following code:

```
Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
Analyzer analyzer = null;
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_1, analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

Document doc1 = new Document();
doc1.add(new StringField("title", "aa", Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(doc1);
indexWriter.commit();

IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(dir);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
// print results using MatchAllDocsQuery
```

And it worked without throwing exception.

Comment: Thanks @mindas.. i will try this. But one thing i always hear from people is we need to use the same analyzer in both indexing and searching otherwise we used to get some wrong search results...

Comment: If your document has this field only, query should be using `KeywordAnalyzer` since this analyzer works with entire stream as a single token.

Comment: Thanks @mindas.. passing analyzer as null when indexing and using TermQuery for searching works fine.. also got some performance gain when i use StringField instead of TextField.